# Are questions about parliamentary procedure on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about Robert's Rules of Order and similar topics on-topic on Law Stack Exchange?

Example question: [When should a point of order be raised for an error by the chair in calling a vote?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85043/when-should-a-point-of-order-be-raised-for-an-error-by-the-chair-in-calling-a-vo)

Comment: Why would it not be on topic? Maybe we are missing something from your question.

Comment: Yes, but asking if they are isn’t.  ;)

Comment: Roberts Rules aren't the law, so it seems to me that the answer would generally be that it's off-topic.

Comment: @bdb484 would you mind posting that as an answer so it can be voted on?

Comment: Whatever the answer for Law.SE, note that there are many questions on this subject over on Politics.SE, where it is definitely on-topic. See, for example, the tags [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) and [procedure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure).

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

Certainly questions about the rules of procedure  used in legislative bodies, such as municipal councils, state or provincial legislatures, or national legislatures (e.g. the US Congress or the UK Parliament) should be on-topic. At the municipal level, a published set of rules such as *Robert's Rules of Order* is often used. At the national level, each body tends to have its own unique rules.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend what the question asks.  If it relates to, for example, these from our [Help Centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications

Then, probably, yes: it will be on-topic. But without knowing the question it's not possible to give a definite answer either way.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

We do not limit ourselves only to the law as enacted and enforced by governments.

Legal questions about private law such as contracts, rules of sport or games, or rules of meetings are fine.

Comment: I agree in general, with some reservations about "rules of sport or games", I think I wiwill ask a separate mera question about that.,

Answer (score -3):

Parliamentary procedure is only on topic, if it is set up with a law or legal document, which makes that law or document the topic of the question.

Comment: Robert's Rules of Order are legally binding in many organizations, because the bylaws specify that RROR govern meetings and laws make the bylaws govern the organization. Is that enough to make RROR on topic?